# Enable/Disable associated product programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog

Is it possible to disable and enable associated products programmatically? Currently i do this for the simple product, but it doesn't seem to be affecting the associated product.

Right now i'm doing something like this:

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_int cpei, catalog_product_entity cpe
            SET cpei.value = '2'
            WHERE cpe.entity_id = cpei.entity_id
            AND cpe.sku = '" . $sku . "'
            AND cpei.attribute_id = 96
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to modify my code a bit, but I managed to make it work with this.

```
$product->setStatus(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
```